# I am having problem to construct minted style listings with tcolorbox. Please help!

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, minted, overleaf, pygments

Here's my latex project on Overleaf.com and errors and logs:

I created a .cls by loading the class file

```
\LoadClass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
```

And then I add some packages essential

```
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[minted,skins,breakable,listings,many]{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
```

Use `\newtcblisting` to create new tcoloredbox of code:

```
\newtcblisting{codecsharp}[1][]{
  title=This is source code in another language (C\#),
  colframe=yellow!50!black,
  width=\linewidth,
  enhanced,
  breakable,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  colback=light-gray,
  listing only,
  listing engine=minted,
  minted language=csharp,
  after={\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent}
}
```

Then, I use the .cls in .tex and write this code in document environment:

```
\begin{codecsharp}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpTutorials
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string message = "Hello World!!";

            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
\end{codecsharp}
```

But there's error occurs:

[image]

And the pdf file looks like:

[image]

By the way, the line 36 in the error log is

```
\end{codecsharp}
```

And it saids

> Package minted Error: Missing Pygment out; \inputminted was

I know that sentence is not finished, grammatical speaking, but that is all.

Comment: Did you enable shell-escape? Can you please post a complete MWE (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`). Maybe also post the entire `log` file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I figured it out, I will write an answer myself if any confront same problem.

Comment: From the screenshot of the error, it looks like you've placed your project's main `.tex` file in a folder, which can cause some problems. Have you tried moving it to your project's root (i.e. outside of any folder) instead?

Comment: Oh, that was not the problem, I tried to pull it out, but it is not helping.

Comment: I believe it's a Overleaf issue because every time I reached a certain number of file in one project, it will fail to compile the `\newtcblisting` command.